# Git : Using actions/checkout@v2 instead of appleboy/ssh-action@master to clone repository to a server

Tags: github-actions, git-checkout

I'm trying to clone a repository from GitHub to a remote server.

My solution using **appleboy/ssh-action** GitHub action was working but I was told the same can be achieved using **actions/checkout@v2** GitHub action.
I tried to just change **- uses:** value to **actions/checkout@V2**` but then the code doesn't work.

I can't find any templates on how to do it using **actions/checkout@v2**. Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
name: deploy to a server on push

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  deploy-to-server:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

  - uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master 
    with:
      host: 123.132.123.132
      username: tomas
      key: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}
      port: 59666
      script:
        git clone https://github.com/Tomas-R/website.git
```

Comment: From the workflow file what I can see is you are trying to run a command over SSH on a remote server. `appleboy/ssh-action` is designed for that. But `actions/checkout@v2` is designed to checkout any repository into your `$GITHUB_WORKSPACE` directory (available on the machine where your GH-action is running).
I think you cannot simply replace `appleboy/ssh-action` with the checkout action.
If you really want to use `checkout@v2`,  you may checkout the repo and then run `scp` to copy the directory to your remote server.

Comment: @RobinRaju yes this is what I'm trying to achieve. 
`scp`  should work but it is a ssh-key based connection with a port 59666. How do I specify all these elements ? The form that is written here for appleboy-ssh action doesn't work with actions/checkout@v2 , so I'm trying to find what would be the form . In form I mean, how do I specify PRIVATE_KEY, port, host, etc. Any source for that ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the documentation of `actions/checkout@v2` says

> This action checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your workflow can access it.

```yaml
   steps:
      - name: Checkout the repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with: 
          # This will create a directory named `my-repo` and copy the repo contents to it
          # so that you can easily upload it to your remote server
          path: my-repo
```

To copy this checked-out repo to a remote server, you may use `scp` command as follows.

```yaml
   # Runs a set of commands using the runners shell
     - name: Upload repo to remote server
       env:
           SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /tmp/ssh_agent.sock
       run: |
         ssh-agent -a $SSH_AUTH_SOCK > /dev/null
         ssh-add - <<< "${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}"
         scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -r -P 59666 my-repo tomas@123.132.123.132:/target/directory
```

By using the above commands we,

- Start `ssh-agent` and bind it to a known location.
- Import the private key from the secret to the ssh-agent.
- Copy contents from `my-repo` to the target directory on your remote server.

This way, the private key is never written to the disk / being exposed.

There is yet another easier way to run `scp` using the [Copy via ssh](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/copy-via-ssh) GitHub action.

```yaml
   - name: Copy folder content recursively to remote
     uses: garygrossgarten/github-action-scp@release
     with:
       local: my-repo
       remote: ~/target/directory
       host: 123.132.123.132
       port: 59666
       username: tomas
       privateKey: ${{secrets.PRIVATE_KEY}}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. Could you also please point out the source, where you found the answer( or got the idea for the answer), just for the future reference., thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar problem.
In my case, problem is this (appleboy/ssh-action@master) action file.
Just replace this action file with other action files from Github Marketplace
I have used LuisEnMarroquin/setup-ssh-action@v2.0.0 action file.

My Workflow File:

```
    name: SSH to Ubuntu EC2
    on:
      push:
        branches:
          - main
    jobs:
      ssh-to-ec2:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
        - name: Checkout code
          uses: actions/checkout@v2

        - name: Set up SSH key
          uses: LuisEnMarroquin/setup-ssh-action@v2.0.0
          with:
            ORIGIN: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
            SSHKEY: ${{ secrets.TEST }}
            NAME: production
            PORT: 22
            USER: ubuntu
        - run: ssh production "ls -la;id; echo hehe > h.txt "
```