# How to git pull at remote server and then recreate the env file using github actions

Tags: github-actions, digital-ocean

I want to have a workflow dispatch triggered GitHub Action that will

1. ssh into a specific digitalocean droplet
2. deploy the code by running `git pull`
3. then recreate the .env file based on the secrets inside the GITHUB repository

I thought 1 and 3 are the hardest part so I concentrated on them.

Two hard requirements are:

A) i want to avoid is writing any secrets and committing them to the repository direct.

B) must work for private GitHub org/repo or user/repo

This is my current workflow file

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: digitalocean-pull-and-setup-env

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the $default-branch branch
  # push:
  #   branches: [ $default-branch ]
  # pull_request:
  #   branches: [ $default-branch ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # SSH into digitalocean droplet
      - name: executing remote ssh commands using password
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}


      # Runs a single command using the runners shell
      - name: Run a one-line script
        run: echo Hello, world!

      # Runs a set of commands using the runners shell
      - name: Run a multi-line script
        run: |
          echo Add other actions to build,
          echo test, and deploy your project.

      # create the env file
      - name: Make envfile
        uses: SpicyPizza/create-envfile@v1
        with:
          DEBUG: False
          DEVELOPMENT_MODE: False
          DJANGO_SECRET_KEY: ${{ secrets.DJANGO_SECRET }}
          directory: /home/django/all_django_projects
          file_name: .django
```

It run successfully no errors. but I don't see the .django env file created in the DigitalOcean droplet.

I think the reason is because GitHub Actions run the steps as separate steps inside the running container.

I don't mind abandoning the my 3 step algo if there's a better solution that achieves my ultimate aim of deploying to a digitalocean with a .env file created from the secrets inside the GitHub repository.

I also found the `actions/checkout`  and `digitalocean/action-doctl` https://github.com/actions/checkout and https://github.com/digitalocean/action-doctl but frankly they confused me so I didn't use them.

Not even sure if it does what I want.

All I want is a simple way to pull down the latest changes on a already running digitalocean droplet and re-create the environment file before I restart the server.

There's also this [answer in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68245226/80353) and it appears to upload the entire repo from GITHUB_WORKSPACE into the remote server, which I think is overkill compared to simply pulling down changes at the server.

The closest I find is maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61449595/80353) which seems to suggest that I cannot nest the action within each other and on top of that I need to write a script.

DO I really have to write a script within the ssh action or I can somehow reuse the `create-envfile` action within the `ssh` action?

Comment: I'm *guessing* that point 1 and 3 might have different answers completely so I would advise you to focus on only one question first. Otherwise, if one person answers 1 and another answers 3, you're not going to be able to accept both.

Comment: It’s an end to end process so points 1 and 3 need to both work together not separately.

Comment: What about creating the envfile first and then running rsync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized I should have fleshed out the whole target scenario more explicitly in terms of hard requirements.

### Target scenario: how to deploy from GitHub to a Ubuntu VPS

#### Hard requirements

Must use:

- Github Actions
- Ubuntu LTS VPS (I use DigitalOcean)

Must see:

- the codebase on the VPS be updated to latest `main` branch
- there is a new .env file in the project path on the VPS

#### Approaches

I discover 2 general approaches.

##### Approach 1. multiple actions + rsync method

Outline:

1. checkout action then rsync to update codebase
2. create-envfile then rsync

This approach uses mixture of GitHub Actions. Namely, [checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout) and [create-envfile](https://github.com/SpicyPizza/create-envfile)

##### Approach 2. ssh-action with bash script + git clone method

1. ssh-action then

   1. git clone using bash script to update codebase
   2. create envfile using bash script

This approach uses 1 GitHub Action but it needs more bash scripting

I chose approach 2 because `git clone` is superior to rsync.

This is my `ci.yml`

```
name: Deploy via SSH
on: [workflow_dispatch]
jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Deploy via SSH
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
        username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USERNAME }}
        key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
        script: |
          # git update to latest codebase on main branch
          cd /path/to/project && git pull
          # updating the .env file
          cat <<EOF > ${{ secrets.ENVFILE_PATH }}
          # start of envfile
          DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=${{ secrets.ENVFILE_DJANGO_SECRET_KEY }}
          # end of envfile
          EOF
          # see end result of envfile
          ls -l ${{ secrets.ENVFILE_PATH }}
```

As for how to save the secrets to your GitHub repo for SSH access, please check this [article](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-deploy-your-application-to-digital-ocean-using-github-actions-and-save-up-on-ci-cd-costs-74b7315facc2)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of approaches I can think of:

1. As you mentioned, replacing the `create-envfile` Action invocation with your own script to dump environment variables to a `.env` file and adding that as an argument to your `appleboy/ssh-action` invocation step. I don't see this as a major burden - you could just copy most of the code from [here](https://github.com/SpicyPizza/create-envfile/blob/master/src/create-envfile.py).
2. Keeping the `SpicyPizza/create-envfile` action step but modifying the output path to a location inside the GitHub Actions runner. Then, `scp` the env file you just created to your droplet. You can do this with your own subsequent `run` step or you could use this [scp GitHub Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/scp-files). File changes by separate steps remain in the runner workspace until the end of the job, and subsequent steps see previous steps' changes on the runner's filesystem.